# Mysterious Event in Android Activity I can't seem to capture

Tags: android

[image]

[image]

I am writing an app for a custom android device that includs a barcode scanner. Inside my app is a WebView.

Out of the box, the scanner populates html fields inside the webview without calling any library methods.

I can see the text in Android Studio's profiler. I have attached pictures of the event. For testing, I created a barcode encoded with the text "Your Text".

My problem is, I need to capture this event or replicate it, but I don't know what type of event it is. I originally thought the text was part of the Key Event, but the String is not there. It seems like it is another key press event. Is there a way to capture or replicate this mysterious event?

Answer (score 1):

it might be the key-code assigned to the scanner's trigger button (just press and hold it for a second)... when the duration of the key-event changes, this should be proven. `KEYCODE_BUTTON_R1` is `103`:

> On a game controller, the R1 button should be either the button labeled R1 (or R) or the top right trigger button.

there might be configuration bar-codes available, to enable/disable/change that key-code.

Comment: Thanks, I can capture the KEYCODE_BUTTON_R1 event, but it seems there is a second event with the String payload. The KEYCODE_BUTTON_R1 doesn't contain any payload.

Comment: @LuckyPrime a single key-code event cannot contain any payload, hence it is the payload - while a barcode is a bunch of key-codes. in case bi-directional communication is being supported, sending that `KEYCODE_BUTTON_R1` to the scanner might even trigger a scan. Zebra & Honeywell support this, while they are not simple "keyboard wedge" scanners, but send/receive data in XML envelopes.